# How To Build a Template Framework for Joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla-template

If you are a Joomla developer, I am sure you have heard of or used the T3, Gantry, Zen Grid, YJSimpleGrid, or the new Gavern template frameworks built by various sites.

I want to make one for my own company, we have some specific sites we build where pieces are always the same etc. But I am trying to figure out just how to start building one? Have you built one? How would you build one?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to create a joomla component for it, the component core objectives should be setting up the template. To eliminate the work redundancy you can create component settings as well. Let me know If you wish to have more info.

Comment: I would love to have more info please. Thanks!

Comment: To keep things pretty simple, you can first try creating setting based templates. Your template setting will be saved in xml format. Later on you can control this template through component if only required

Comment: I actually have built many templates, with options parameters etc. lol I have even published a tutorial on it at nettuts ;)  what I mean is a whole framework deal, likes those others. Do they just modify existing files?

Comment: then develop the component that can change ur template structure , many of the framework that i know does the same